# Items are not horizontally aligned

Tags: html, css

The 4 divs have a width of 23% and are displayed inline-block, they have a height of 220px and margin 0. The issue is that they are not horizontally aligned

I tried to change the height and width already and removed the margin but that does not fix it.

**It looks like this...**

[image: screenshot]

```css
.aside-column {
  width: 23%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="aside-column aside-column1">
  <h4>Lufthansa vs Airbus</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, exercitationem nulla? Ea rerum necessitatibus ratione optio iure. Aliquid?</p>
  <div class="aside-readMore">
    <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aside-column aside-column2">
  <h4>Bill Gates History</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero in labore assumenda tempora nostrum nisi possimus saepe dolor incidunt voluptatem, iure cum atque!</p>
  <div class="aside-readMore">
    <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aside-column aside-column3">
  <h4>Tescos Stabbing</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quis quaerat quo reprehenderit?</p>
  <div class="aside-readMore">
    <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aside-column aside-column4">
  <h4>Amazon Forest Fire</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur aliquid sint tenetur.</p>
  <div class="aside-readMore">
    <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give `vertical-align:top;` to `.aside-column` class.

```css
.aside-column {
  width: 23%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="aside-column aside-column1">
  <h4>Lufthansa vs Airbus</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, exercitationem nulla? Ea rerum necessitatibus ratione optio iure. Aliquid?</p>
  <div class="aside-readMore">
    <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aside-column aside-column2">
  <h4>Bill Gates History</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero in labore assumenda tempora nostrum nisi possimus saepe dolor incidunt voluptatem, iure cum atque!</p>
  <div class="aside-readMore">
    <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aside-column aside-column3">
  <h4>Tescos Stabbing</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quis quaerat quo reprehenderit?</p>
  <div class="aside-readMore">
    <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aside-column aside-column4">
  <h4>Amazon Forest Fire</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur aliquid sint tenetur.</p>
  <div class="aside-readMore">
    <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Most welcome...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a parent container which is a flexbox.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.aside-column {
  width: 23%;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="aside-column aside-column1">
    <h4>Lufthansa vs Airbus</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, exercitationem nulla? Ea rerum necessitatibus ratione optio iure. Aliquid?</p>
    <div class="aside-readMore">
      <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside-column aside-column2">
    <h4>Bill Gates History</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero in labore assumenda tempora nostrum nisi possimus saepe dolor incidunt voluptatem, iure cum atque!</p>
    <div class="aside-readMore">
      <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside-column aside-column3">
    <h4>Tescos Stabbing</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quis quaerat quo reprehenderit?</p>
    <div class="aside-readMore">
      <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside-column aside-column4">
    <h4>Amazon Forest Fire</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur aliquid sint tenetur.</p>
    <div class="aside-readMore">
      <a href="">Continue Reading</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```